# How to get element as an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

The question might not be clear, so let me clear it here. I have a loop :

```
 var a = document.getElementsByTagName("*"), b = 0;
   for ( b = 0; b < a.length; b++ ) {
      if ( a[b].hasAttribute(":hide") ) {
        a[b].style.display = 'none';
      };
   };
```

Now, this loop will look for if the `:hide` attribute is present in any element in the html document and if it find one then it will hide the element. Lets say that there are 5 no. of `h1` elements with 3 of them have the attribute :hide, they will get hidden. But how to know in what value of "b" does the element fall. Its a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], or a[4]. Can this be found out ? If question is till not clear, please comment down below. Is my concept wrong ? If yes then please explain me how this loop works !

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the failing elements to an array in the `else` part of the condition

```
 var failing = [];

 var a = document.getElementsByTagName("*"), b = 0;

   for ( b = 0; b < a.length; b++ ) {
      if ( a[b].hasAttribute(":hide") ) {
        a[b].style.display = 'none';
      }
      else
        failing.push(a[b])
   };
```